# Order column by number of commas in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id_police':['s123','s124','s125','s126','s127'],
                   'raison':['dog','cat','cow','dog, cat, cow','dog, cat'],
    })
>>> df
  id_police         raison
0      s123            dog
1      s124            cat
2      s125            cow
3      s126  dog, cat, cow
4      s127       dog, cat
```

And I want to order by column `raison` in a DESC fashion like this (and ID is reset but id_police is preserved):

```
  id_police         raison
0      s126  dog, cat, cow
1      s127       dog, cat
2      s123            dog
3      s124            cat
4      s125            cow
```

Please help, I think I need a `lambda` function for this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can using `count` + `argsort`

```
df.iloc[(-df.raison.str.count(',')).argsort()]
Out[12]: 
  id_police         raison
3      s126  dog, cat, cow
4      s127       dog, cat
0      s123            dog
1      s124            cat
2      s125            cow
```

Comment: This is the most pythonic way to get such result, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort_values` for this and before that creating a count column for `,`:

```
df['count'] = df.raison.str.count(',')
df = df.sort_values('count', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.drop('count', axis=1)

print(df)
  id_police         raison
0      s126  dog, cat, cow
1      s127       dog, cat
2      s123            dog
3      s124            cat
4      s125            cow
```